# How do I make sure only one update is "applied"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let's say I define a table like so:

```
create table anonymized_example(
  id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  status varchar(50) not null,
  other_columns varchar(50));
```

Now, sometimes to threads in a cluster may want to update this table at the same time. My idea is to run a query like this:

```
update reservation_proxy_order,
set status='WORKING_ON_IT',
where id=?,
and status <> 'WORKING_ON_IT';
```

As far as I understand, this means that one of the threads will get to update first, and return out that 1 row was updated, and the other(s) will report that they updated 0 rows. And that's great. Now one thread in the cluster will start doing it's thing, and the rest will be left alone.

However, there's something that doesn't sit quite right with me. Is this a valid way to do this? Or are there better ways that should be considered?

Comment: Or you could use transactional locking https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/

Comment: If you use an update, you get an exclusive lock. The article you posted agrees with this. But the question remains, what will the next updates return once they get the exclusive locks?

Comment: It should return whatever is currently in the table until the transaction commits and the lock is released.

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit Next update will not take an exclusive lock because no rows to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `and status <> 'WORKING_ON_IT` should assure that only the first update is applied.  `(0 row(s) affected)` means nothing was changed.

Test for yourself by running it multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it by running it sequentially and seeing that it works, the question is what happens when it gets run in parallel. :)

Comment: @HaakonLøtveit The answer is that it does not run in parallel.  That is the wonder of a database.